# 401(k) funds - taxes living abroad?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, non-resident

If you plan to retire overseas, are you going to be taxed from the US or from the country overseas?

I was not able to find any rules that could answer that question for traditional 401k funds.

I would like to know for US-citizens and non-US-citizens. 
Where do you have to pay the taxes?